# display rotation and resizind issue in qt

Tags: c++, qt5

I am developing an embedded Qt app and I want to rotate my display.

My display size is 178*220. So I create my ui 178*220.

Now my problem is when I rotate display 90 degree it is not displaying properly.

During the rotation I am resizing it.

```
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(parent);
    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(parent);
    QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = scene->addWidget(this);
    view->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    view->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    view->setStyleSheet("QGraphicsView { border-style: none; }");
    view->setScene(scene);
    view->resize(176,220);
    view->rotate(90);
    view->show();
```

Actually I am thinking we can not make 176 to 220 but we can make 220 to 176.

What should I do ?

Comment: What do you mean with "is not displaying properly"?

Comment: As I remember, I've made a rotation directly in QML when had such requirement.

Comment: According to our requirement  i am not using QML coding.